# Esav Tribal Wives

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayishlach, esav

Most the tribes of Esav do not have wives listed among the husbands, yet we find ([Bereishis 36:39](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.36.39?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en))

> וַיָּמָת בַּעַל חָנָן בֶּן־עַכְבּוֹר וַיִּמְלֹךְ תַּחְתָּיו הֲדַר
>   וְשֵׁם עִירוֹ פָּעוּ וְשֵׁם אִשְׁתּוֹ מְהֵיטַבְאֵל בַּת־מַטְרֵד בַּת
>   מֵי זָהָב׃
>
> And when Baal-hanan son of Achbor died, Hadar succeeded him as king;
>   the name of his city was Pau, and his wife’s name was Mehetabel
>   daughter of Matred daughter of Me-zahab.

What is so significant about this wife in contrast to the others that it was worthy of recognition in the Torah?

Answer (score 3):

The Baal Haturim (citing Bereishis Rabah 83:4) explains that Mehetabel descended from powerful, wealthy people and it was only through marrying her that Hadar became King. Therefore it mentions her by name (and her lineage) in the context of his kingship.

Comment: And what? What Halacha comes from this knowledge? THe Torah omits many other important facts, but this? I think your answer (albeit correct) fails to answer the OP's question of *What is so significant*?

Comment: @AlBerko You seem to have misunderstood the question. The OP didn't ask 'what is the halachic significance'. There are many things the Torah mentions that don't have halachic significance.

Comment: Please explain ANY significance you see in this explanation.

Comment: @AlBerko It is a narrative significance; her lineage was the reason he was king. That is what is significant about her in contrast to the other wives.

Comment: I understand that point is important for historians, but Torah-wise, Judaism-wise, why mention that at all? Don't take it personally, I just criticize the interpretation for inconsistency.

Comment: @AlBerko I understand your objection, but it is beyond the scope of the original question. By focusing on the word 'significance' to the exclusion of the rest of the question, you may be misconstruing the intent of the OP. OP is asking what is special about this wife as opposed to the others. He is not asking what practical life lesson we learn from it.

Comment: @NJM Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: THat's how I understood "*that it was worthy of recognition in the Torah"*